# Excel PivotTable without summation of Values

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am struggling with an Excel PivotTable problem although I am not sure that a PivotTable is the best solution.  I have a vertical table that has the format shown below, that I am trying to pivot to a horizontal table.   My Google searches have come up with a mix between 'can't be done' or 'change your format'.

The format that I have in my worksheet looks like this:

| Date | Name | Metric | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10-19 | Project1 | temp | 5 |
| 10-19 | Project1 | degree | 30 |
| 10-19 | Project2 | temp | OK |
| 10-19 | Project2 | degree | 18 |
| 10-20 | Project1 | temp | 45 |
| 10-20 | Project1 | degree | 18 |
| 10-20 | Project2 | temp | OK |
| 10-20 | Project2 | degree |  |

What I am trying to do is have a format that looks like this

| Name | temp | degree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Project1 (10-19) | 5 | 30 |
| Project1 (10-20) | 45 | 18 |
| Project2 (10-19) | OK | 18 |
| Project2 (10-20) | OK |  |

So I am pivoting the metric column into the header and my columns are the distinct project by date.  The problem that I am having is that when I pivot this in Excel I want the to see the real values of the 'value' column that is associated to the corresponding date, project, and metric and not some aggregate value.  Is there a way to do what I want?

Here is a screenshot of what the data looks like when I pivot it with Name and Date as rows and Metric as the column:

[image]

*For clarity: the table format shown above of what I want is just to make the text editor happy, in Excel I actually have the Name and Date fields in the 'Rows' field so that I have a grouping by project and date.*

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, project1(10-19) can have two temp/degree metrics? Maybe just add an index column in your data and use that as the 3rd thing to pivot by in the rows...

Comment: No.  Each day I collect day for each project for each metric.  In this case there are 2 metrics (temp and degree) tracked across the projects (Project1 and Project2).  It is starting to feel like the process that I have to retrieve this data is going to have to do the pivot for me outside of excel.

Comment: When I create a pivot with your data, there are no problems. Everything looks precisely like your desired output. If each Project and Date has just one Temp value and just one Degree value, then there's nothing to aggregate.

Comment: agree with @Isolated, there shouldn't be a problem. Edit your question with a screenshot of your pivottable fields (section with filters/columns/rows/values. Perhaps something is going on there...

Comment: The dataset that I have is much larger than what I posted in my question; I agree with what you guys said that the format I provided does pivot correctly.  Looking deeper in the dataset not all of the values are numbers; some values are empty and some are even strings.  It seems like this is causing the problem. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Index_Match]

or maybe I would suggest to have a format like in the image attached
copy paste below formulas ;
cell F4 = H4&" "&"("&TEXT(@G4:G11,"mm-d")&")"
cell L4 = SORT(UNIQUE(F4:F11),1,1,FALSE)
cell M4 = INDEX($J$4:$J$11,SMALL(IF($M$3=$I$4:$I$11,ROW($I$4:$I$11)-ROW($I$4)+1),ROW(1:1)))
cell N4 = INDEX($J$4:$J$11,SMALL(IF($N$3=$I$4:$I$11,ROW($I$4:$I$11)-ROW($I$4)+1),ROW(1:1)))